# Mounting ephemeral device on ECS/Fargate, owned by unprivileged user

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I used to run ECS/EC2 (and there it worked). But now I've moved the service over to ECS/Fargate and for some reason the mount is owned by `root:root`, which means my app (that runs as unprivileged user) can't write to it!

I create my service using Terraform:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "mytask" {
  family = "mytask"
  container_definitions = templatefile("${path.module}/task-definitions/mytaskdef.json", {
    [...]
  }
  volume {
    name = "media"
    efs_volume_configuration {
      file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.myefs.id
    }
  }
  volume {
    name = "static"
  }
  [...]
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "myservice" {
  name = "myservice"
  cluster = aws_ecs_cluster.mycluster.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.mytask.arn
  [...]
}
```

and in my container definition JSON, I specify the mountpoint:

```
[
  {
    "name": "mycontainer",
    "essential": true,
    "image": "myimage",
    "user": "myuser:mygroup",
    "privileged": null,
    "mountPoints": [
      {
        "sourceVolume": "media",
        "containerPath": "/var/www/myefsmount",
        "readOnly": false
      },
      {
        "sourceVolume": "static",
        "containerPath": "/var/www/mymountpoint",
        "readOnly": false
      }
    ],
    [...]
  }
]
```

Results in:

```
root@ip-10-0-0-241:/app# mount | grep mymountpoint
/dev/nvme1n1 on /var/www/mymountpoint type ext4 (rw,relatime)
root@ip-10-0-0-241:/app# ls -ld /var/www/mymountpoint
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul  7 16:42 /var/www/mymountpoint
root@ip-10-0-0-241:/app#
```

If I run the same commands (created from exactly the same IaC!), I get:

```
myuser@8db224841833:/app$ mount | grep mymountpoint
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /var/www/mymountpoint type xfs (rw,noatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
myuser@8db224841833:/app$ ls -ld /var/www/mymountpoint
drwxrwsr-x 14 myuser mygroup 210 Jul  7 13:27 /var/www/mymountpoint
myuser@8db224841833:/app$
```

The AWS documentation for task defs and volumes isn't quite clear on what happens if you do NOT use EFS, Docker or FSx mounts. It speaks about ephemeral, but it doesn't not clearly specify that that is the default so I'm a bit confused to what's actually happening here.

But nowhere can I find anything about how to make sure that an ephemeral mount is mounted as a specific user.

I don't understand why it works perfectly on ECS/EC2, but not ECS/Fargate! I'm using the same image, same IaC. The only difference is the underlying architecture.. Or am I missing something!?

Weirder part is that the EFS mount works exactly as intended:

```
root@ip-10-0-0-241:/app# mount | grep torchweb_media
fs-longfsid.efs.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com:/myefsmount on /var/www/myefsmount type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,noresvport,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.0.0.241,local_lock=none,addr=10.0.8.149)
root@ip-10-0-0-241:/app# ls -ld /var/www/myefsmount
drwxrwsr-x 2 myuser mygroup 6144 Jun 22 08:41 /var/www/myefsmount
root@ip-10-0-0-241:/app#
```

Comment: According to the documentation, that should work. However, the only use case for doing this on Fargate I can think of is sharing an ephemeral volume between multiple containers in a single task, and you don't appear to be doing that. Do you really need to create a separate ephemeral mount on top of the ephemeral file system already provided by ECS/Fargate?

Comment: I AM doing that, I just didn't show that part. Because I figured it was irrelevant :). But I DO have exactly the same problem in the other container - owned by root:root :(. Although, in that it doesn't matter, because it's read-only (Nginx providing SOME of the files - don't ask, legacy stuff that I'm working on getting rid of).

Comment: Got it, just wanted to make sure you weren't going down this path if you didn't need to. Looking at the documentation for this feature here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/bind-mounts.html I do see that you could define a docker `VOLUME` in one of your Dockerfiles, and then expose that to the other container. That volume could be empty if you wanted, and when you mount that type of volume ECS uses the `USER` specified in the Dockerfile as the volume owner. Maybe that would get you past this?

Comment: I also think you should post your issue here: https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues since it seems like it is a bug in the way Fargate ephemeral volumes are mounted.

Comment: I did consider that Dockerfile "hack", but I wanted to make sure it's not something I'm missing in ECS/Fargate first.. Creating a new image isn't completely straight forward unfortunately. AND I need to investigate what side effects that will have on other uses (developers machines etc). Thanx for the link to the tickets, I look at them and see if there's anything in there that can help, otherwise I'll create a new one - it must/should be possible to specify "mount user".